# GRASS GIS related issues!

Tags: raster, grass-gis

(1) How to create a multiband raster from a set of single band rasters (except when somebody talks about doing a `r.composite`).

I attempted creating a `raster3D` and it turned out that it is not possible to display it with the GUI.

(2) How to subset a raster dataset (at least I do not see a direct command for doing so)

Edit (following the comment to my humble question): If my observations are wrong, please let me know the answer to these questions.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. This a Q&A site, not a support forum. Do you have a question? If not, perhaps you really just wanted to raise a bug report for QGIS?

Comment: OP has arrived at conclusions that GRASS GIS can't do certain things without sufficient research. He/she could have asked how to perform such operations using GRASS GIS (particularly for 2nd conclusion).

Comment: This thread appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to ask two distinct questions so my recommendation is to focus on the one which is most important to you and remove the other into a separate Question.

Answer (score 2):

Re 1) Where should the multiband information come from if you have only a single band? In case, there is the "#" operator in r.mapcalc to pseudo-split singleband data.

Re 2) Of course you can subset raster map (again, with r.mapcalc). See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

While we are at it, see also
http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_processing

Comment: OOPS! I meant creating a multiband raster from a set of single band rasters. I have reworded the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, easy: create a "group" with i.group of the maps to be put into the multilayer GeoTIFF (or other multilayer format). Then export to that format with "r.out.gdal input=group output=multilayer.tif". Voilà...